# A use of Hahn-Banach and Riesz Representation

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space.  Suppose $X$ is not a singleton set and $C(X)$ denotes the space of continuous functions on $X$.  Do we have that for all $L \subset C(X)$ a nondense subspace, there exist two probability measures which agree in integration against all elements of $L$ but not on $C(X)$?  Here $L$ is assumed to contain the constants. (This last sentence was added after my comment, but before the answer.)

Comment: Apparently the answer is no, because to any $X$ you can adjoin 1 more point disjointly, and the same issue as with the singleton set arises.  So the singleton set is a legitimate counterexample, not a "cheap" one.  So now I'm wondering if the answer is "yes" if $X$ is connected, say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any counterexamples. If $L$ is a subspace that is not dense in $C(X)$, then (by Hahn-Banach) there is 
a nonzero linear function whose kernel contains $L$. By  Riesz representation, this functional is given by integration against a signed measure $\nu$. By Hahn-Jordan decomposition theorem, $\nu$ is $\nu^+-\nu^-$ where both measures are 
positive (and finite, since $\nu$ is). Since $L$ contains constants, $\nu^+(X)=\nu^-(X)$. Normalize the measures, and you are done.

In the case of $X$ being a singleton, the statement remains  true, vacuously: there is no $L$ that satisfies the assumptions.

Comment: Ah I see yes, just as soon as I added that $L$ contains all constants, the singletons are no longer a problem.  So it's not singleton sets or connectedness issues that pose a problem.  The pathologies are all within the case where $L$ may not contain the constants.

Comment: @Jeff The  pathologies are not so pathological either; since you insist on two measures being normalized, they automatically agree on constants. Thus, you are actually assuming that the measures agree on the span of $L\cup\{1\}$. The rest goes through as above, unless of course this span is dense.